# Send multiple images using 2d Array in android to post data to server using retrofit

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, retrofit, retrofit2

I have to upload gallery images using `2d` array in android. i need to use hash map for this purpose but i am confused how to do that can any one please suggests any solution or sample code for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your hash map like this

```
HashMap<String, String> images=new HashMap<String, String>();
meMap.put("image name","image path");
```

you can create key value pairs like this or can change according to your requirement but note one thing keys should be unique for every key i.e image name should be different every time because if same will be inserted again then its value will be overidden.

Comment: can i use a random number for this to avoid override?? @Kartika Vij

Comment: Yeah you use random number or time stamp

Comment: can you please show me a sample code because i am stuck in it here is my requirment @Kartika Viij ....                                                            
profile_gallery[0]['base64_string'] string base64_string
profile_gallery[0]['name'] string name
profile_gallery[0]['type'] string type


profile_gallery[2]['base64_string'] string base64_string
profile_gallery[2]['name'] string name
profile_gallery[2]['type'] string type


profile_gallery[3]['base64_string'] string base64_string
profile_gallery[4]['name'] string name
profile_gallery[3]['type'] string type

Comment: I prefer sending image in multipart instead of base 64

 RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), modApplication.itemFileList.get(0));
                    item_image1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("item_image1", modApplication.itemFileList.get(0).getName(), requestFile);